# Spacetime Visual Aid Concept

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, visualization

How do you envision spacetime?  What visual-aid(s) have helped you the most?

We have all probably seen the “bowling ball on a trampoline” construct but the big problem with that is it represents spacetime as a 2-dimensional plane with a 3-dimensional mass influencing it.  Spacetime is infinitely unidirectional, there are no gaps in it, and it is flexible.

In my mind I picture the known universe as a big (cosmic-scale) cube (sphere, whatever) of absolutely clear and frictionless Jell-O.  This Jell-O is so clear that we have not come up with a way to observe it because we do not know yet what properties we are even looking for.

Contained within this Jell-O are “pinch points” (PP) where the Jello-O is stretched in all directions inward toward the center of individual mass objects.  Every mass object contained within the Jell-O creates its own PP regardless of how small it is.  The further you move away from a PP, the less stretched the Jell-O is until you are in the vast spaces between galaxies where the Jell-O is at a more-or-less constant tension or steady-state.  Super-massive objects in the Jell-O have a proportionately large PP.  These PPs in the Jell-O have attractive properties that affect all other PPs because the Jell-O is the connecting tissue, if you will, that connects all mass objects together.

An asteroid (a relatively small PP with velocity) for example, will follow a straight line through the clear, frictionless Jell-O until a PP influences it and attracts it closer to it, thus altering its course.  This repeats over and over until the asteroid eventually is forced to either collide with a PP and add to its mass, or is captured by a PP and establishes an orbital relationship with it (which does not add to the PP object’s mass directly, but adds to its PP mass influence on the Jell-O).

Light waves are even influenced by the PPs and their trajectories are altered.  Incidentally, it is the existence of the clear frictionless Jell-O of spacetime that allows light to even propagate to begin with as even a light wave needs some medium to move through (yeah this is currently arguable but I think we will discover at some point that its true).

I wish I had the graphic art skills to create a visual representation of this concept as its difficult to put a visual idea into descriptive text.

Relativity says that an observer A near the event horizon of a supermassive PP will experience time differently than an observer B out in the steady-state Jell-O.  If you are imagining the stretched, flexible Jell-O around the supermassive PP, the “fabric” of the Jell-O has less “Jell-O fabric available per distance” (in other words, the same amount of Jell-O is spread out over a larger spatial expanse as it approaches the supermassive PP) available than the steady-state Jell-O in between galaxies does.  This causes observer A to experience less time (events per spacetime) relative to what observer B experiences.  Inside the event horizon of the supermassive PP, where observer C is, the fabric is no longer stretched, it is super-compacted which would conversely make an insanely increased “time available per distance” fabric Jell-O where time would move so fast (so many events could occur per available spacetime Jell-O) that a single event that would take fractions of a nanosecond to observer B would encompass relative eons to observer C.

Observer C would live out their entire normal life in what would seem to be a fraction of an instant to observer B and even a fraction of that instant to observer A.

Time is probably best regarded as a constant then by observer B out in the steady-state Jell-O between PPs.  We here on earth are more-or-less out in the steady-state Jell-O but even our little planet, our proximity to our sun, our proximity to our galaxy center of mass, our proximity to our local group, has the cumulative mass influence to create a significant enough PP that the Jell-O of space time is stretched just enough that our “time available per distance” is slightly less than observer B and observer B would watch us live and die a bit faster than he does.

Imagine how much information could be contained within a supermassive PP relative to the information available outside of it to us here on earth due to the super-condensed spacetime inside it; and all the trillions of events happening there every nanosecond that we experience here.

So, how do you envision spacetime and how could I add to my analogy to even better my understanding?

Comment: There are already visuals of 3D space around massive objects, it's just a cube of points and lines that become stretched towards masses in the cube, you can find any number of these images online. You can encode the time related effects as coloration if the image.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc

Comment: @ Stephane Rollandin, that is almost exactly what I was visualizing, just so long as the motion of the animation at say...  0:20 is time continually "falling" toward the center of mass.  I think spacetime is static and can be compressed or stretched; you dont have this infinite collection of spacetime forming at the center of mass, just a pinch point of elastic spacetime.  Thank you for that link, thats got to be the coolest visual aid Ive ever seen.